# Inverse z transform - Pair of complex conjugate poles

Tags: discrete-signals, impulse-response, z-transform, poles-zeros

How can I perform the inverse z-transform on the following $H(z)$ to be able to calculate a **real-valued impulse response** $h[n]$?
$$
H(z)=\frac{z^2}{z^2+0.8\sqrt{2}z+0.64}
$$
My idea was to find an inverse z-transform on my list of transformations, which basically does what I want with a similar transfer function (nothing too special about that idea). Well, I found the following:
$$
H(z)=\frac{p z \sin(\alpha)}{z^2-2p z \cos(\alpha)+p^2}
$$
I then tried to adjust the transfer function. First I did that for the denominator and found it had a pair of complex conjugate poles $0.8e^{+j\frac{3\pi}{4}}$, and $0.8e^{-j\frac{3\pi}{4}}$. That seems great, my desired form of the transfer function has similar poles $pe^{+j\alpha}$, and $pe^{-j\alpha}$. Therefore I would substitute $p=0.8$ and $\alpha=\frac{3\pi}{4}$. But now I don't know how to go further, what do I do with the numerator? Is this approach valid at all?

Comment: That seems fine. You just need to include another gain term on the numerator, because you may no get $p\sin(\alpha)$.

Comment: You mean I add a term in the numerator of the first $H(z)$, like $az^2$ and $a=psin(\alpha)$? Is it ok to do that?

Comment: Yes, the thing to do is to decouple the constant in the numerator from $p$ and $\alpha$ in the denominator.

Comment: The result I got:
$$
H(z)=\frac{az^2}{z^2+0.8\sqrt{2}z+0.64}=\frac{0.8 z \sin(\frac{3\pi}{4})}{z^2-1.6 z \cos(\frac{3\pi}{4})+0.64}z=0.8^nsin(\frac{3\pi}{4}n)u[n+1]
$$
Is it correct like this? Still not sure why I can add the gain term

Comment: It may be that the gain term is already $p \sin(\alpha)$. In general, it won't be.

Comment: Well, if its not, then I cannot apply the transformation right? What do I do then?

Comment: Of course you can still apply the $z$-transform! it will be the same, up to a gain term.